# If condition inside foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

I'm new to laravel. How can i put if condition inside the foreach loop in blade template

my code is:

```
enter code here@foreach ($data as $data)
question: {{ $data->qid }}
Your answer: {{ $data->answer }}
Correct answer: {{ $data->anskey }}
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($data as $data)
    Question: {{ $data->qid }}
    Your answer: {{ $data->answer }}
    @if($data->anskey === $data->answer)
        You correct
    @else
        You incorrect
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
####Ols
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach

####new syntix for and if
@forelse ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
    <p>No users</p>
@endforelse
```